# Kaggle competition: categorical variables

Tags: python, categorical-data, kaggle

Under the categorical variables exercise there is the last part of generating test predictions. I have written the following code but getting an error. I am unable to understand the error and why it's saying X has 148 features and random forest is expecting 155 features.

My code:

```
ohencoder=OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)

# X_test.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
h_cols_test = pd.DataFrame(ohencoder.fit_transform(X_test[low_cardinality_cols])) # Your code here

h_cols_test.index=X_test.index

num_X_test= X_test.drop(object_cols, axis=1)

OH_X_test=pd.concat([num_X_test, h_cols_test], axis=1)
#randomforest mode-----------------------------

model=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,  random_state=0)
model.fit(OH_X_train, y_train)

preds_test= model.predict(OH_X_test)
#output---------------

output=pd.DataFrame({'Id': X_test.index,
               'SalePrice': preds_test})
output.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

---

Error message:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:1692: FutureWarning: Feature names only support names that are all strings. Got feature names with dtypes: ['int', 'str']. An error will be raised in 1.2.
  FutureWarning,
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:1692: FutureWarning: Feature names only support names that are all strings. Got feature names with dtypes: ['int', 'str']. An error will be raised in 1.2.
  FutureWarning,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1524045498.py in <module>
     12 model.fit(OH_X_train, y_train)
     13 
---> 14 preds_test= model.predict(OH_X_test)
     15 
     16 output=pd.DataFrame({'Id': X_test.index,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in predict(self, X)
    969         check_is_fitted(self)
    970         # Check data
--> 971         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
    972 
    973         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X)
    577         Validate X whenever one tries to predict, apply, predict_proba."""
    578         check_is_fitted(self)
--> 579         X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
    580         if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or X.indptr.dtype != np.intc):
    581             raise ValueError("No support for np.int64 index based sparse matrices")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    583 
    584         if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):
--> 585             self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
    586 
    587         return out

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    399         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
    400             raise ValueError(
--> 401                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    402                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    403             )

ValueError: X has 148 features, but RandomForestRegressor is expecting 155 features as input.
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `OH_X_train.shape` and `OH_X_test.shape`? (_after_ #randomforest mode---------, before training)

Comment: Also i compiled same code and get following error

Comment: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

Comment: (1168, 155) for OH_X_train,  OH_X_test.shape=(1459, 153)

Comment: I have added following code # lowcardinality_col=[col for col in object_cols
                    if X_test[col].nunique()<10]

Answer (score 0):

You have different amount of features in training and test sets. So, there may be features present in the training that the model cannot find in the test, or features in the test for which the model was not trained.

A possible reason for this error is the one-hot-encoding when it's performed separately in each data set: there may be values for categorical variables that are only present in one of the tests.

One solution is to perform the OHE before splitting the data or, alternatively, you can use `fit_transform` with your training set and then only `transform` with your test set. **Remember** that you should always use `transform` when processing novel data, and this is a general rule for all scikit transformers.

Of course you should also make sure that all other trasformations, like droping columns were performed the same in both training and test sets. Pipelines are here your best friends.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Kindly make me understand this scenario: 1- trainand test data splitting already in the program. X_train->fit_transform and X_valid ->transform only.  2- then comes the X_test dataset where i have to apply trained model. The code is above. If i just used X_test.transform..I still receive error that fit is not used.

Comment: I used hot encoder and i adjusted the column through drop and concatination..why still column mismatch is in shape. IF i used X_test.dropna(axis = 0, inplace=True), column mismatch ..if I dont use then error is ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Comment: In exercise, Kaggle drops missing data for training set and also for X_test dataset:
X = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv', index_col='Id') 
X_test = pd.read_csv('../input/test.csv', index_col='Id')
X.dropna(axis=0, subset=['SalePrice'], inplace=True)
y = X.SalePrice
X.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1, inplace=True)
cols_with_missing = [col for col in X.columns if X[col].isnull().any()] 
X.drop(cols_with_missing, axis=1, inplace=True)
X_test.drop(cols_with_missing, axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: Can we solve it without Pipelines at this stage. I just want to experience this.

Comment: I'm trying to guess your problem based on the code you are showing. For example, I don't know where `OH_X_train` is coming from. I assume because of the name that you applied oh-encoding to it, but also, because it's not after the declaration of `ohencoder` I assume you encoded it with a different encoder. One that was fitted to the training set. If so, if a value appear in one set but not in the other, you're going to have different number of columns. But, as said, is my best guess. Can you check which columns are present in OH_X_train but not in OH_X_test and viceversa?

Comment: Dropping missing data is fine. Just make sure to drop the same columns from both training and test databases.